# Haskell Euler's totient error?

Tags: haskell

I am trying to use Haskell to compute Euler's totient function:

```
totient m = product [(p - 1) * p ^ (c) | (p, c) <- prime_factors_mult m]
```

However, this does not at all compute the coprime factors less than m. Is there an error in my logic somewhere? I think that `(p-1)` is the correct number but it is not giving me the results I need..

Comment: Shouldn't `p^c` really be `p^(c-1)`? For a prime `p`, `totient p == p-1`.

Comment: @ErikR oh I see. I will try that!